# How to Validate Google Map ID which is used for Map Options

Tags: javascript

How to Validate Google Map ID which is used for Map Options

```
hdr_loadGoogleMap: function() {
        var me = this,
            vFormPanel = me.getFormPanel(),
            vFldValues = vFormPanel.getFldValues(['install_gmapikey','install_gmapid','install_gmapcoor','install_gmaptype']),
            vContainer = vFormPanel.down('container[hostCmpId=mapContainer]'),
            vLat,
            vLng,
            vGmapcoor = vFldValues['install_gmapcoor'].split(','),
            vGMapTypes = {
                'map': 'roadmap',
                'satellite': 'satellite',
                'terrain': 'terrain',
                'labels': 'hybrid'
            };


vLanguageCode ='en';
        Ext.Loader.loadScript({
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=inavlidkey&v=3.55&language='+vLanguageCode,
            onLoad: function () {
                 me.hdr_gmap = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    layout: 'fit',
                    header: false,
                    border: false,
                    itemId: 'map',
                    style: 'padding: 0; border-width: 0;',
                    draggable: false,
                    height: 290,
                    width: 350,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'uxgmappanel',
                        useCurrentLocation: true,
                        center: {
                            lat: vLat,
                            lng: vLng
                        },
                        mapOptions: {
                            zoom: 14,
                            mapTypeId: 'roadmap', 
                           ** mapId: 'IncorrectedValue'**
                        }
                    }]
                });
                vContainer.add(me.hdr_gmap);
            }
        });
```

In above, i am sending Incorrected Value for the Map ID. Please suggest.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/mapConfigs:batchGet. in this call, getting response like Map ID is not valid.

I need to display alert message in javaScript if MAp ID is invalid.